# Should service layer return entity model that isn't mapped to an actual database table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, ef-code-first

I have a web app with following design.

`View -> Controller -> Service || Repository -> DB`

For example :

Entity Model

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }
    //rest of property here..
}
```

Context

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } //register entity class as DbSet
    ...
```

Repository

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> List()
{
    return _customer.AsEnumerable();
}

public void Insert()
{
    //...
}

public void Update()
{
    //...
}
```

Service

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> MaleCustomerList()
{
    return _repo.Customer.List().Where(w => w.Gender == "M");
}

public IEnumerable<Customer> FemaleCustomerList()
{
    return _repo.Customer.List().Where(w => w.Gender == "F");
}
```

So far we have no problem because service is returning entity model which is mapped to an actual database table. But what if I need to do some complex queries that return a completely different object, for example I need to group certain customer and calculate their percentage. I will need to return something like `IEnumerable<CustomerGroup>` where `CustomerGroup` is completely different with `Customer`, but it is not an actual table (because I don't need it) in the database.

So my question is, is it okay to make a new Entity model

```
public class CustomerGroup
{
    public int GroupName { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

but the different is that it's not registered in the Database Context `DbSet` so my service can return this type?

Comment: it's ok to use separate class. and it should be not in Context, but in your service layer (I think it's your BL, not?)

Comment: business layer, where logic if situated

Comment: Yeah, service is where I put all my business logic.

Comment: than it's totaly normal that you have there different classes than in your db